Figuras 3d con matplotlib
Ultimamente e estado intentando hacer una figura 3d con matplotlib y he llegado hasta aquí, pero no sé mas, alguien me podría ayudar?
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg as FigureCanvas
import time

class main(tk.Tk):
    
    """
    clase principal
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)


        #Combo?
        self.Combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=['Graph1', 'Graph2'],
                                     state="readonly")
        self.Combobox.pack()
        self.Combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.Draw())

        #Gráfica
        framegrafica = tk.Frame(self)
        framegrafica.pack()
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig, master=framegrafica)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection="3d")
        
        self.Draw()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.Draw()

    def Draw(self):
        if self.Combobox.get() == "Graph2":
            framegrafica = tk.Frame(self)
            framegrafica.pack()
            self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig, master=framegrafica)
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection="3d")
            self.axes.clear()
            x = np.linspace(np.random.randint(-5,0), np.random.randint(5,10), 40)
            y = np.linspace(np.random.randint(-5,0), np.random.randint(5,10), 40)
            X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
            Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)) #Se supone que esta x e y tienen que ser en mayusculas pero yo lo cambié
            self.axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
            self.canvas.draw()

        else:
            framegrafica = tk.Frame(self)
            framegrafica.pack()
            self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig, master=framegrafica)
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection="3d")
            self.axes.clear()
            #Seno
            x = np.linspace(-6, -6,30)
            y = np.linspace(-6, -6,30)
            X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
            Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)) #Aqui esta en version original, mayús

            #Esfera
            # u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
            # v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
            # X = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
            # Y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
            # Z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

            #Superficie
            # X = n.array([[1,3], [2,4]])
            # Y = np.array([5,6], [7,8])
            # Z = np.array([[9,12], [10,11]])

            self.axes.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
            self.axes.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z')
            self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ventana = main(None)
    ventana.mainloop()

Aquí el problema, al elegir un gráfico en el menú en vez de generar una figura con unos valores aleatorios que ya antes tendría que haberse elegido no hace absolutamente nada y de verdad que no entiendo porque pasa eso. He intentado de todo pero no ha funcionado y como no se que hacer os lo dejo en el estado original porque eso pensé que podría ayudar. No sé mucho del programa porque me guié por una ayuda que me dieron y entonces pues claro no puedo ayudar mucho, yo supongo que el error estará en la funcion de dibujar y bueno espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

El primer problema está aquí:
self.Combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.Draw())
                                                    ^^
                                                    ^^
                                                    ^^ Estás llamando al método

a bind le tienes que pasar una referencia a un objeto llamable que será llamado cuando el evnto tenga lugar. Ahora mismo lo que le pasas es el retorno de self.Draw, que es None. Debe ser:
self.Combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.Draw)

Por otro lado, self.Draw al ser llamado a través del mecanismo de bind se le pasa un argumento que es el evento. El método debe aceptarlo aunque no lo use.
Por último:

Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)) #Se supone que esta x e y tienen que
ser en mayusculas pero yo lo cambié

¿Por qué lo cambiaste? x e y (en minúscalas) en tu código son los arrays retornados por numpy.linspace(), dos arrays de una dimensión. Si luego haces Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)), Z será un array unidimensional también, y plot_surface() necesita que Z (igual que X e Y) sea un array bidimensional.
Tienes una muy buena explicación de como funciona Axes3D.plot_surface() en la respuesta a esta pregunta en SO (en inglés):
How does the x, y, z in plot_surface work?
El código quedaría algo asi:
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg as FigureCanvas


class main(tk.Tk):
    
    """
    clase principal
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #Combo?
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=['Graph1', 'Graph2'],
                                     state="readonly")
        self.combobox.pack()
        self.combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.draw)
        self.combobox.current(0)

        #Gráfica
        self.framegrafica = tk.Frame(self)
        self.framegrafica.pack()
        
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig, master=self.framegrafica)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")

        self.draw()

    def draw(self, _event=None):
        if self.combobox.get() == "Graph2":
            x = np.linspace(np.random.randint(-5,0), np.random.randint(5,10), 40)
            y = np.linspace(np.random.randint(-5,0), np.random.randint(5,10), 40)
            X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
            Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X ** 2 + Y ** 2))
        else:
            #Seno
            x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)
            y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)
            X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
            Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X ** 2 + Y ** 2))

        self.axes.clear()
        self.axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
        self.axes.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z')
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ventana = main()
    ventana.mainloop()


